# DSO_ROS is not giving right coordinates after taking turn (left/right)

Tags: ros, autonomous-car

**Hi all ,**

i got stuck in a problem and really need your help.

**Goal:**
 I want to move little Toy vehicle autonomously (localization and mapping) and want to get distance covered by vehicle using DSO in real time. For now i want to move vehicle in square of 2x2 meters using dso_ros.

**Work Done:**
I'm getting coordinates of live camera by using dso_ros, I'm getting a matrix (camToWorld.matrix 3x4() in publishPoseCam SampleOutputWrapper.h), where first 3x3 is for rotations and last 3x1 is for translation(x,y,z if i'm not wrong). 
When i move camera straight forward from any position then i got change in X-coordiante (it starts from 0.000 and ends on 0.7 when camera moved 2 meters forward ). Then i stopped it and take turn and move forward for 2 meters and so on (to draw square of 2x2 meters).

**Problem:**
When i take first turn (left/right) and then move it forward then no one coordinate gets change or update, dso gives me coordinates continuously but with very minor changes. I don't know which coordinate now i have to use to calculate distance after taking turn, so i get lost when i take first turn and not be able to draw square.  Please help me with this and guide me where i am wrong, I shall be very very thankful to you. I have been stuck in it from past 2 weeks.

Thanks.

Comment: a general advice, in such cases you need a through debug (if you fully understand the system) ,and what will be a big save of your time is a Great IDE and Plug-ins , also Great Googling,..